# Swagger UI Sort not working for version v2.1.4

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-php

Hi i have implemented Swagger UI using JSON object but the issue is that the "paths" (API calls) are not showing in alphanumeric order instead i have given the "apisSorter" as alpha in JavaScript.

JSON output is showing correctly in web console as sorted when i use debug tool but while showing in web page its showing in order which i mentioned in annotations page which are not in alphanumeric way.

Below is the code:

```
docExpansion: "none",
                    jsonEditor: false,
                    apisSorter: "alpha",
                    defaultModelRendering: 'schema',
                    showRequestHeaders: false
```

Even i tried to sort JSON from server side but no help.

Below is the code:

```
usort($swg_result, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
        return $b->paths > $a->paths ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing to this solved the issue:

```
apisSorter: "alpha",
operationsSorter : "alpha",
```